# Export default in typescript isn´t working for commonjs

Tags: node.js, typescript, ts-node

im trying to make an express application but with typescript. With ts-node.

But when i try to export a function or class with **export default** it not works

`helloWorld.ts`

```
export default () => {
    console.log('Hello world!');
}
```

`app.tss`

```
import helloWorld from "./helloWorld.js";

helloWorld();
```

It returns the error: `Error: Cannot find module './helloWorld.js'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are importing from `.js` extension (`helloWorld.js`) in your `app.ts`!

You should import from `.ts` extension or omit the extension

```
import helloWorld from "./helloWorld.ts";
```

or

```
import helloWorld from "./helloWorld";
```